# OpenGL compressed textures and extensions

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures

I've an *nVidia Quadro NVS 295/PCIe/SSE2* card in which when I do `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`, print out the values and grep for "compress", I get this list

- GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage
- GL_ARB_texture_compression
- GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc
- GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
- GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
- GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc
- GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
- GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc

But then again [`glCompressedTexImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCompressedTexImage2D.xml) says that `glGet` with `GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS` returns the supported compressions, which only gives

- 0x83f0 = GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT
- 0x83f2 = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT3_EXT
- 0x83f3 = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT

these three values.

Now why does `glGet` not expose the other compression formats that my card can process? Say LATC, RGTC or VTC?

Also why am I not seeing corresponding DXT3 or 5 extensions in the first list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now why does glGet not expose the other compression formats that my card can process?

Because NVIDIA doesn't want to. And really, there's no point. The ARB even decided to deprecate (though not remove) the COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS stuff from GL 4.3.

In short, don't rely on that particular `glGet`. Rely on the extensions. If you have GL 3.0+, then you have [the RGTC formats](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Red_Green_Texture_Compression); that's *required* by GL 3.0+. If you have [EXT_texture_compression_s3tc](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression), then you have the "DXT" formats. If you have [EXT_texture_sRGB as well](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression#sRGB_and_S3TC), then you have the sRGB versions of the "DXT" formats. And so forth.

> Also why am I not seeing corresponding DXT3 or 5 extensions in the first list?

*ahem*:

> - 0x83f2 = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_**DXT3**_EXT
> - 0x83f3 = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_**DXT5**_EXT

Those are just different forms of S3TC.

Comment: Btw, thanks for the quick reply. I'm reading your excellent tutorials on OpenGL and I had a question in that too. Didn't know how to contact you (since the tutorial didn't've a contact email), hence registered myself in BitBucket.org and sent you a message there.

Comment: The link seems to be broken :( Thus, I don't know what are guaranteed formats for OpenGL 3.0+

Answer (score 2):

> why am I not seeing corresponding DXT3 or 5 extensions in the first list?

You are.  They're covered by [`GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_compression_s3tc.txt).